# Unity Light baking causes artifacts

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

I am getting artifacts when I use light baking.

When I apply the same material to a Cube generated in Unity it does not happen to the cube. But on the imported model you can see

[image: Model rendered with baked light]

I have checked the model and tried everything I can think of. There is others with the [same issue](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1394691/severe-lightmap-artifacts.html?childToView=1468998#answer-1468998) on the Unity Forum.

Any ideas ? I dont seem to get help from the Unity Forum. :(

Comment: Did you try increasing lightmap padding? Also make sure all the generate lightmap uv of the fbx files are turned on. If it still doesn't work then try to increase the lightmap resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You should finetune your lightmap settings. There is a pretty good tutorial I know from Youtube that explanes how it works. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnG2gOKV9dw